# GSAP: SVG not centering as expected

Tags: svg, gsap

## 2 questions about [this CodePen](https://codepen.io/clozach/pen/BaaxjjG)

[image: Screenshot from CodePen showing a red and a green balloon.]

1. Why isn't the red balloon ending up centered on the crosshairs, given that I've set `transformOrigin:"50% 50%"`?
2. Why does the green balloon seem to have its origin set to `"left top"` when, according to [this doc](https://greensock.com/docs/v2/Plugins/CSSPlugin#transformOrigin), it should default to `"50% 50%"`?

## Relevant code (I think)

*HTML*

```
<svg class="container" fill="#f0c0c0" style="background: linear-gradient(to top, #ddfdff, #6dd5fa, #2980b9);
;" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="200" height="200" viewBox="0 0 200 200">
  <g id="green-balloon">
    <path … />
    <path … />
    <text …></text>
  </g>
  <g id="red-balloon">
    <path …/>
    <path …/>
    <text …>⚡️</text>
  </g>

  <line x1="0" y1="100" x2="200" y2="100" stroke="white" stroke-width=".5px"/>
  <line x1="100" y1="0" x2="100" y2="200" stroke="white" stroke-width=".5px" />

  <defs>…</defs>
</svg>
```

*JS*

```
var redBalloon = $("#red-balloon");
var greenBalloon = $("#green-balloon");

var tl = new TimelineLite({onUpdate:updateSlider});

tl.set(greenBalloon, {x:100, y:200})
  .set(redBalloon, {transformOrigin:"50% 50%", x:100,y:200})
  .to(greenBalloon, 1, {scale:2, y:100})
  .to(redBalloon, 1, {scale:2, y:100})
```

*CSS*

Not applicable.

Comment: For reference, this was [answered over on the GreenSock forums](https://greensock.com/forums/topic/21823-svg-not-centering-as-expected/?do=findComment&comment=102792)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Per [OUSblake's answer](https://greensock.com/forums/topic/21823-svg-not-centering-as-expected/?tab=comments#comment-102792) on the GreenSock forums:

> `transformOrigin`/`svgOrigin` affect scale, rotation, and skew. And `svgOrigin` uses the `<svg>` element's coordinate system. So `svgOrigin: 50% 50%` means everything is going to transform around 100,150 in the svg. `transformOrigin: 50% 50%` would be the center of the balloon. To center your element, use `xPercent: -50` and `yPercent: -50`.

After providing a [demo on Codepen](https://codepen.io/osublake/pen/f90d0b83280cd1de6ae71815f0f553e7), he continues:

> It sounds like you were expecting transformOrigin to behave like in Adobe products, where changing the registration point causes the element to move. It doesn't, but that's what `xPercent`/`yPercent` are for.
>
> Just use those with a `transformOrigin: 50% 50%`, and everything should be pretty easy with curves.

He even went so far as to demonstrate [motion along a path](https://codepen.io/osublake/pen/b929da30a619b3b2b34c397fe378ea20). Super helpful!